# Inserting substring in string at specific index counting from end. How to in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have problem with mysql insert().

I have strings of variable length (15-20 chars) in a table, and I need to add 4 characters to every string. The catch is that I need to add them exactly 4 chars before the end of the string.

For example, given input string `1234567890-123` I need to add 'ABCD' before '-', so that the string becomes `1234567890ABCD-123`.

- I tried with insert() function but it can't do it.
- Is there solution for this or do I need to write an application to do it?
- I use MySQL 4.1.

Comment: Are you aware that MySQL 4.1 dates back to 2004? [We're on 5.5 now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Product_history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) provide a solution:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE(`column`, '-', 'ABCD-');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
UPDATE yourTable 
SET yourString=CONCAT(LEFT(yourString,(CHAR_LENGTH(yourString)-4)), "ABCD", RIGHT(yourString,4))
```

As always with such queries, test it first on a small sample of the data before running it.

Answer (score 2):

```
CONCAT( SUBSTR( str, 0, LENGTH(str) - 4 ), new_characters, SUBSTR( str, -4 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on the database side you can take advantage of [Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) in MySQL.

Comment: Apologies i missed that in the Original Question

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
select insert('1234567890-123', locate('-', '1234567890-123'), 0, 'ABCD');
```

I have used the literal '1234567890-123', but for a column, it would look like:

```
select insert(col, locate('-', col), 0, 'ABCD');
```

Note that this inserts the string before the hyphen `-`. Alternatively, you could insert it at a particular position, or at a position back from the end: `length(col) - 4`