# Add specific character before / after / certain position of the text string in mysql

Tags: mysql, split

I would like to get value like this : 1/2/3/4/5 from this value : 12345 in mysql without using a function.
can somebody  help me ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/7024330/808901

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of appallingly poor design

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.
I got solution of my problem here
[Get image url in prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683386/get-image-url-in-prestashop)
and here is sql for adding character (here it is a '/') between each character of a string
SELECT if (length(table.field)>1,concat(mid(table.field,2,1),'/'),''),if (length(table.field)>2,concat(mid(table.field,3,1),'/'),''),if (length(table.field)>3,concat(mid(table.field,4,1),'/'),''),if (length(table.field)>4,concat(mid(table.field,5,1) FROM table